# Referencing System.Windows.Controls and Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics in the same project?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, xna-4.0

Can I use **"System.Windows.Controls"** and "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics" assemblies in the same project without facing any problems from Microsoft Certification process.

Because it has been said that, **"4.2.5:-The application must not call any APIs in the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game assembly or the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics assembly when using any methods from the System.Windows.Controls namespace."**

Comment: I dont think that is allowed.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184843(v=vs.92).aspx check this out .. it might help

Comment: "Can I do something that I am specifically told that I cannot do?"  Uh, no?

Comment: @Will unless the docs are out of date ;)

Answer (score 1):

No you can't .The [requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184844%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) are explicit. Can you describe what kind of functionality are you looking for? Do you want to [combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202938%28VS.92%29.aspx) Silverlight and the XNA Framework in a Windows Phone Application? Do you want to use one of its types?

Answer (score 0):

The Marketplace certification requirements are explicit - and they were correct for applications which target WP7.0. However they aren't accurate for WP7.1 "Mango" apps.

For WP7.1 it is possible to write a combined SL/XNA application. There is even a code sample for this on MSDN (see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202938%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)).